# Unable to open file from winscp (ec2) which was mounted to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, winscp

I have mounted s3 bucket on my EC2 instance using the details mentioned here at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_s3_sftp. Also, I updated the bucket policy.

From winscp, I can see the list of files, add new files, delete files uploaded via s3 web portal, and open files uploaded by me via winscp.

However, I cannot open the file from winscp which I uploaded from s3 web portal. I get the following error.

[Permission denied to read s3 object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzgZC.jpg)

Comment: What permissions are associated with the Role assigned to your EC2 instance? By the way, Amazon S3 is not designed to be mounted to systems. You might instead consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access content on Amazon S3.

Answer (score -1):

WinSCP does not support S3 ACL automatically, you should set read permission for each uploaded file, manually.